# Setting "echo on" globally for batch scripts

Tags: batch-file, echo

I have experienced (random) weird corruption of environment variables from consecutive calls of multiple (3d party) batch scripts. These individual scripts call `@echo off`.

Is it possible to force `echo on` by environment variable/other means or I need to go to the every script and comment/remove the line to see what has been actually executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm quite sure that this is not possible. You can't force your system to simply ignore a command like `ECHO OFF`. The only way to I can think of as a workaround is to write a script which replaces all `ECHO OFF` commands in you bat files before execution and restoring them afterwards.

Take a look at this: https://superuser.com/questions/351661/how-do-i-force-echo-on-for-a-batch-file-without-editing-the-file